# How to toggle Keyframe after by hot key? ( Grease Pencil )

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to quickly switch between the values 1 and 0 in a *Keyframe after* by hot key. How to assign a hot key to these actions? Just write a script?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your custom keyboard shortcut like this:

[image]

Key points

- When setting toggle shortcuts use `wm.context_toggle`
- When it pertains to the active object use `active_object`. Then you want to edit the data of the object, which is `data` and the attribute can be copied from onion skinning tab, which is `ghost_after_range`
  The result is `active_object.data.ghost_after_range` you need to enter in Context attribute field
- If you add it under 3D View (Global) the keyboard shortcut will trigger it in all 3D View modes.